# Requested URI is too large when using a GET string

Tags: php, image, uri

I am building an API for an app of ours. In the API I plan to store either an base64 encoded version of an image or the raw Json Data.

When we are attempting to send (as a GET) to my API, We get the error :

**The Requested URI is too large**

The image we are attempting to post is : [png data](http://pastebin.com/f7gEH30H)

I am open to any suggestions as to what we can do to avoid this error.

We have thought maybe storing the data as a text file and I then in PHP get the files_contents and then store in the DB. However that will solve our png problem, But not our raw json_encoded data.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what we can do?

Many Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you use GET or POST? It's not clear.

Comment: Hi @caCtus at my API end I retrieve it as a get request. Sorry for it not being clear..

Comment: does the request modify anything in the API? (I'm assuming so, since you're saying you want to store something in the DB)  If so, I would suggest to change from GET to POST

Comment: Hi @watcher I've requested our API sender change it to POST and we get the same error still.

Comment: Have you tried POST yourself or are you just trusting your API sender? ;)

Comment: Ha, I have @eyp I have tried it with "postman" for Google Chrome and get same error.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed you're using PHP. Then I think you must change the value of **upload_max_filesize** parameter within php.ini. The default value is 2M, so if your file is greater you must increase the max size.

And of course, still use POST instead of GET.